# GWT deprecated: PlaceHistoryHandler.register?

Tags: gwt, deprecated

I have a GWT app that I ported to GWT 2.4. Now I geta deprecated warning on this line:

```
 historyHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);
```

"The method register(PlaceController, EventBus, Place) from the type PlaceHistoryHandler is deprecated"

Is there a better way to achieve the same result here or is it safe to ignore the warning?

```
public void onModuleLoad() 
     {
          // Create ClientFactory using deferred binding so we can replace with
          // different impls in gwt.xml
          ClientFactory clientFactory = GWT.create(ClientFactory.class);
          EventBus eventBus = clientFactory.getEventBus();
          PlaceController placeController = clientFactory.getPlaceController();

          // Start ActivityManager for the main widget with our ActivityMapper
          ActivityMapper activityMapper = new AppActivityMapper(clientFactory);
          ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper, eventBus);
          activityManager.setDisplay(appWidget);

          // Start PlaceHistoryHandler with our PlaceHistoryMapper
          AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper = GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
          PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(historyMapper);
          historyHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);
          RootPanel.get().add(appWidget);

          // Goes to place represented on URL or default place
          historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is deprecated because the `EventBus` type has moved from `com.google.gwt.event.shared` to `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared`. As indicated in [the JavaDocs for `PlaceHistoryHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryHandler.html) (which don't make this especially clear) switching your `EventBus` to the `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus` type will resolve the deprecated warning. That said, for now, both `EventBus` types are functionally identical and the warning is safe to ignore.

Comment: I found that the Activity.start method still needs the old EventBus.  So at the moment you either have to use the deprecated PlaceHistoryHandler register  or you have to roll your own Activity base class.

Comment: @Deanna Two reasons that isn't true: Any `Activity` that is started isn't given the exact `EventBus` you passed in to `PlaceHistoryHandler.register`, as `PlaceHistoryHandler` is only concerned with mapping history to places. Additionally, while the old EventBus subclasses the new one, the `EventBus` instance given to an activity is actually a different instance anyway, designed to allow resetting all registered handlers when that activity is ended.

Comment: @Colin. Gonna have to disagree with you, at least if you follow the mvp pattern laid out by ray ryan at google io.  There is one event bus for the whole app.  It is a singleton.  It is all the same one and only eventbus.  The event bus has to be global to the app so that different activities can talk to each other through it.  http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=wokmi6krbgtqxnww&number=1  or from google io  https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fevents%2Fio%2F2011%2Fstatic%2Fpresofiles%2Fdrfibonacci_devtools_high_performance_gwt.pdf slide 35.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - Look at ActivityManager's `stopperedEventBus` field, which wraps the global event bus instance. This allows any given Activity to do all the registration it wants, and never need to worry about unwiring events, ActivityManager will unwire when the activity is shut down and the new one started. There is _effectively_ one event bus, all events published/subscribed on the stoppered version still get passed around, but it is a way to remove dead handlers for inactive activities. Try it and see - they aren't the same EventBus instances.